# When we use the word 'time' in spacetime and time dilation are we understanding that time has the same meaning for both entities?

Tags: spacetime, time, time-dilation

When we talk about time dilation are we talking about spacetime or is time dilation a separate kind of time?

Comment: Yes, it has effectively the same meaning in both terms. There is no point in grasping at this too tightly--the meaning of the word 'time' is not directly demonstrable, as opposed to the meaning of a word like 'banana.'

Answer (score 1):

Time dilation is not a kind of time. It is the ratio between the time measured between two events in an inertial frame for which those events are not in the same place and the time measured between those events for the frame in which those events are in the same place (called the *proper time* of the process consisting of those events).

A geometric way to look at it is that time dilation is a partial description of how spacetime looks from another point of view. In non-curved 4-space, combining time dilation, length contraction, and an appropriate shift of origin maps between coordinate systems which have the following property: the time axis $ct$ is parallel to the line segment connecting the present and future of an object stationary with respect to the origin at a particular time; and there are three space axes at right angles to each other and the time axis. (It's 4-dimensional space, so there are four orthogonal directions.) See: [wikipedia - spacetime diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_diagram).

Comment: Thank you for this eloquent answer. I think you are saying yes the ‘time’ element in both concepts are part and parcel of the same thing……sorry for the laymens terms !